# Can I use /etc/hosts to map localhost:3000 to a specific domain?

Tags: facebook, express, oauth-2.0, localhost, web-hosting

For development purposes I would like to map `127.0.0.1:3000` (localhost on port 3000) to something like `local.example.com`. I want to do this because I am testing an application that incorporates Facebook's SDK (OAuth). It's real pain to have to login to Facebook and change the registered domain for my application each time I make development changes locally. So in my `/etc/host` file I have the following:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1:3000  local.example.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

`local.example.com` `<- 404 but localhost:3000 <- works`

How can I correctly alias localhost:port to a domain?

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The HOSTS file helps map hostnames to IP addresses; this has nothing to do with TCP ports.